# Python 3.6.1 tkinter Scrollbar behavior

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

At a Python 3.6.1 tkinter Text Widget with a lot of rows the added horizontal scrollbar varies length while the vertial one is scrolled (due to the different row lengths)

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

filemenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="menu1", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="menu2")
text = Text(root, wrap=NONE)
scrollbarVertical = Scrollbar(root, orient=VERTICAL)
scrollbarHorizontal = Scrollbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL)
scrollbarVertical.config(command=text.yview)
scrollbarHorizontal.config(command=text.xview)
scrollbarVertical.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NSEW)
scrollbarHorizontal.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
text.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbarVertical.set)
text.config(xscrollcommand=scrollbarHorizontal.set)
text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Could you please post a **minimal** code showing your problem?

Comment: The problem is, that the scrollbar shouldn't move...

Comment: this is not what Right leg meant as minimum code. He was speaking about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we cant do anything to help without seeing all the relevant code to the problem. This includes how you are placing the scrollbars and in what frames

Comment: You can create a small example with a text box and 2 scroll bars. This should suffice to provide a working example of your problem.

Comment: Now I added a sample program that has the same issue as mine. Sorry that I didn't got that

Comment: Is there any workaround for this issue? It is not intuitive for a code editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing you can do about it -- the fundamental design of the horizontal scrollbar depends on the length of the longest *visible* line.

Comment: so the only way to avoid this is expand all lines to an equal length with spaces?!

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the only way to avoid it. Even that will be difficult unless you use a fixed width font.

Comment: As my tool is only displaying stuff it's easy to check the maximum length and extend the others equally. But in general it's a bad behavior of tkinter...